# How to update the value of a key in a .yaml file using golang?

Tags: go, yaml

How to update the value of a key in a yaml file using go language?

Comment: https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml

Answer (score 0):

To update the value of a key in a yaml file

1. You need to deserialize(means store []byte array to go object) yaml file content
2. Then Update what you expect
3. Finally serialize (means store go object to []byte array) and rewrite into file

Ref: https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml. That's it!.